# Are NSPathControl and NSPathControlItem full of bugs or is it me? (yosemite)

Tags: cocoa, swift, osx-yosemite, nspathcontrol

Apple changed NSPathControl to work with NSPathControlItem's in Yosemite.

But from where I am sitting, these new classes don't work at all.
I am trying to display a custom path in my data structures, but I have similar problems with a regular file path. Is it me or is it Apple?

Here is my code:

The first snippet works as in, it will show a path. But that is about all that works.

```
//MARK: notifications
func selectionDidChange(notification : NSNotification)
{
    if let item = notification.object as? Group
    {
        //get "path" components
        var components : [String] = [item.title ?? "a"]
        var ancestor : Group? = item.parent
        while (ancestor != nil)
        {
            components.append(ancestor?.title ?? "b")
            ancestor = ancestor?.parent
        }
        components.append("")

       //convert to url
        let path = ("MyScheme:/" + "/".join(components.reverse()))
        pathControl?.URL = NSURL(string: path.stringByAddingPe
     }
 }
```

Clicking any part of the path to try to get any property out of the NSPathControlItem does not work at all. Everything returns nil.

```
@IBAction func select(sender : AnyObject)
{
    println(sender.clickedPathItem??.title)
    println(sender.clickedPathItem??.URL)
}
```

If I try to build a path with NSPathControlItem, I can not set any properties (title, url).

```
    pathComponent.URL = NSURL(string: path.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    //let url : NSURL? = NSURL(string: "/")
    //let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/") 
    //pathComponent.URL = path as NSURL
    pathComponent.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "/atttributes")
    self.pathControl?.pathItems = [pathComponent]
    println(pathComponent.description)
```

Also NSPathControlItem is not supposed to be subclassed.

What is going on here?

**edit**

There is a problem with NSPathControlItem as far as I can tell. 
A helper function to create a NSPathControlItem.

```
    func pathItem(title: String, imageName: String) -> NSPathControlItem
{
    let item = NSPathControlItem()
    item.title = title
    item.image = NSImage(named: imageName)
    return item
}
```

A test function to create NSPathControlItem's and print out their title.

```
    var pathItems : [NSPathControlItem] = []
    for title in ["a","b","c"]
    {
        pathItems.append(self.pathItem(title, imageName: NSImageNameFolder))
    }

    for item in pathItems
    {
        println(item.title)
    }
```

The expected output is three lines with a, b and c. I get nil, b, nil.

If you set the pathItems on a NSPathControl directly, it will work.

```
self.pathControl?.pathItems = [
self.pathItem("a", imageName: NSImageNameFolder),
self.pathItem("b", imageName: NSImageNameFolder),
self.pathItem("c", imageName: NSImageNameFolder)]
```

However, if you set the pathItems indirectly, all goes to hell.

```
self.pathControl?.pathItems = pathItems //array of NSPathControl (see above)
```

**Edit 2**

I had another look at this. I configure a NSPathControlItem in the pathItem function. Here I set the title. Makes no difference if I set the  attributedTitle. Inspecting the item with lldb shows the correct (attributed)title value.

But when I assign the array of NSPathControlItem's to the NSPathControl, the title has a value of "" and the attributedTitle is uninitialized.

Comment: I have a similar question: How to customize the icons appearing on the NSPathControl?

I have published my question [here][1] and I hope to get some suggestions; moreover I'll take inspiration with this posts... hoping Apple has fixed the bugs!


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61096120/use-of-nspathcontrol-to-represent-virtual-path

Comment: I haven't looked at this in a long time. Go to Francesco's question for a more up to date Q&A.

Answer (score 9):

`NSPathControlItem` is seriously broken. As of 10.11.3, it contains the following method, as decompiled by Hopper:

```
int -[NSPathControlItem release](int arg0) {
    [arg0->_secretCell autorelease];
    objc_assign_ivar(0x0, arg0, *_OBJC_IVAR_$_NSPathControlItem._secretCell);
    rax = [[arg0 super] release];
    return rax;
}
```

This is evidently supposed to be a standard `dealloc` override, which releases the ivar, zeroes it out, and calls super. But instead, for some unknown reason possibly related to illegal drugs, it's a `release` override. This means that the moment one of these objects is released, even in the course of some harmless manipulation, it self-destructs and becomes unusable.

I created some code to use the runtime to eliminate the bad `release` override and substitute in a proper `dealloc` override. This is barely tested and use at your own risk:

```
extension NSPathControl {
    class func fix() {
        let itemClass = NSPathControlItem.self
        let superclass: AnyClass = class_getSuperclass(itemClass)

        let releaseSelector = Selector("release")
        let releaseMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(itemClass, releaseSelector)
        let superReleaseIMP = class_getMethodImplementation(superclass, releaseSelector)

        if method_getImplementation(releaseMethod) != superReleaseIMP {
            method_setImplementation(releaseMethod, superReleaseIMP)

            let ivars = class_copyIvarList(itemClass, nil)
            var offsets: [Int] = []
            var cursor = ivars
            while cursor.memory != nil {
                let ivar = cursor.memory
                if String.fromCString(ivar_getTypeEncoding(ivar))?.hasPrefix("@") == true {
                    offsets.append(ivar_getOffset(ivar))
                }
                cursor++
            }
            free(ivars)

            let superDeallocIMP = class_getMethodImplementation(superclass, "dealloc")

            let dealloc: @convention(block) UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8> -> Void = { obj in
                for offset in offsets {
                    let ivarPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<COpaquePointer>(obj + offset)
                    let unmanaged = Unmanaged<AnyObject>.fromOpaque(ivarPtr.memory)
                    unmanaged.release()
                    ivarPtr.memory = nil
                }

                typealias DeallocF = @convention(c) (UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>, Selector) -> Void
                let superDeallocF = unsafeBitCast(superDeallocIMP, DeallocF.self)
                superDeallocF(obj, "dealloc")
            }
            let deallocIMP = imp_implementationWithBlock(unsafeBitCast(dealloc, AnyObject.self))

            class_addMethod(itemClass, "dealloc", deallocIMP, "v@:")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not just full of bugs, it is also not documented. The documentation for `NSPathControlItem` is missing in the *AppKit Framework Reference* .. so odd.

I'm getting the same results as you. This alternative that uses `sender.clickedPathComponentCell()` works ok for me though:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var pathControl: NSPathControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pathControl.URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/System/Library/Fonts")
    }

    @IBAction func pathItemSelected(sender: NSPathControl) {
        if let cell = sender.clickedPathComponentCell() {
            println(cell.URL)
        }
    }
}
```

This correctly prints the partial paths that I clicked on.